# Does one have to bring a physical document for the proof of residency for the global entry interview?

Tags: usa, global-entry

[https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1380/~/trusted-traveler-program---what-do-i-need-to-bring-to-my-interview%3F](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1380/%7E/trusted-traveler-program---what-do-i-need-to-bring-to-my-interview%3F) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/save/https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1380/%7E/trusted-traveler-program---what-do-i-need-to-bring-to-my-interview%3F)) says:

> The following original documents are usually required:
>
> […] Documents providing evidence of residency. Examples are: driver's license (if the address is current), mortgage statement, rental payment statement, utility bill, etc. This is not required for minors.

Does one have to bring a physical document for the proof of residency for the global entry interview, or is it ok to show an electronic version of it (e.g.,
on a laptop or tablet)?

Comment: My global entry interview was done at a counter. It would have been very awkward to handle a laptop, and difficult for the officer to view it. I recommend bringing a printout even if the document was originally electronic.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan my global entry interview was done in a private room in the CBP office. it would have been very easy to handle a laptop and very easy for the officer to view it.

Comment: If the OP knows their interview will be in a private office, electronic-only is practical, but bringing a paper copy would be harmless and cost a tiny fraction of a cent. If they do not know the physical situation for their interview, they should plan for the most inconvenient in the known range.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan sometimes when travelling it's not straightforward to get access to a printer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Any case you know: [Is there any printer at Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) that airline passengers can use?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/147656/1810)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I called my local CBP office at my local airport and verified that they will accept electronic utility bills or mortgage statements, to simply verify your home address. The officer said this was acceptable.

Comment: Despite the requirement being an "original document."

Comment: @phoog if it is electronic, it is the original (I haven't gotten a paper mortgage statement in decades now). Or a paper pay stub. Or... But, I would believe they would take a printout unless they want me to bring a laptop and jack into their network. (As I recall, I just handed over my drivers license and that was it).

Comment: @JonCuster for things like mortgage statements, sure, but not driver's licenses.

Comment: @phoog - for sure, we aren’t there quite yet!