# Is there any printer at Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) that airline passengers can use?

Tags: airports, electronic-items, taiwan, taipei, tpe

Is there any publicly available printer at Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) that airline passengers can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple businesses within Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport that provide printing / photocopying service.

## 7-eleven / ibon Kiosk in Terminal 1

The [7-eleven](https://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/store2_detail/7-11) in Terminal 1 (B1) has [two ibon Kiosks](http://www.ibon.com.tw/event/FLA/index.html), a self-service machine that supports printing and scanning of documents (instructions [here](http://www.ibon.com.tw/pdf/web/Picture_print.html)):

> You can print out any documents or pictures saved in the memory card, USB, or email the attachment to ibon@ibon.com.tw at ibon Kiosk in any 7-ELEVEN stores anytime. All the printing requirements will be easily met.
> (Options of paper types: A4, A4-160lb, A3 and 4x6)

ibon has independently confirmed the location of their kiosks via [their own directory](http://www.ibon.com.tw/retail_inquiry.aspx#gsc.tab=0) (Chinese only, but I can confirm the address is that of TPE Terminal 1):

[image: Search result on ibon kiosk in Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport, result in Chinese.]

## hi-life - may or may not be closed

While [hi-life](http://www.hilife.com.tw/serviceInfo_photocopyFax.aspx) provides printing, photocopying and faxing services in their stores. It looks like they do not have a store in TPE anymore (a search within TPE's own website yielded a cached link that [leads to nothing](http://www.hilife.com.tw/serviceInfo_photocopyFax.aspx) upon clicking through).

## Post office in Terminal 2

The [post office](https://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/store3_1/1102) in Terminal 2 (1F) also provides photocopying services, as [confirmed on their directory](https://www.post.gov.tw/post/internet/I_location/index_post.jsp?prsb_no=012135-8) (Chinese only, keyword: 提供影印服務 - providing photocopying services). As of today, the charge is as follow (translation mine):

> 影印服務
>
> 影印文件用紙僅提供A4(21×29.7公分)、A3(29.7×42公分)兩種規格紙張，A4每頁新台幣2元、A3每頁新台幣4元，紙張正反兩面均影印者，按上述收費標準加倍收取。
>
> B5紙張（18.2×25.7公分）比照A4收費、B4紙張（25.7×36.4公分）比照A3收費。
>
> Photocoping services
>
> We only provide photocopies in A4 and A3 format. A4 photocopying cost NTD 2 per page, A3 photocopying cost NTD 4 per page. Double side printing cost double.
>
> B5 paper photocopying is charged at A4 paper rate, B4 paper photocopying is charged at A3 rate.

Answer (score 4):

[According to TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293910-i9303-k12083657-Taoyuan_Airport_Printing_Area-Taiwan.html), the 7-11 convenience store has printers where you can print, scan and fax.

I can't really confirm based [on their website](https://www.7-11.com.tw/in/en.html)  (in English, there is a Taiwan website too) because it's not explicit on there but there is [a phone number](https://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/store2_detail/7-11) to the terminal where the store is located that you probably can call to be sure.